# Why are my WebViewClient methods not present?

Tags: java, android, inheritance

Here is my code. As you can see in the first block of code, I set my WebView object "myWebView" to WebViewClient "SSLTolerantWebViewClient" which inherits from WebViewClient, yet none of the WebViewClient methods are showing up, so I can't use onPageFinished, for example. Any ideas?

```
public class WebAuth extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_auth);
        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new SSLTolerantWebViewClient());
        myWebView.loadUrl("example.com");
        //myWebView.onPageFinished(args); This method doesn't appear, nor do any other WebViewClient methods

    // other basic activity methods
}
```

Other class:

```
public class SSLTolerantWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
        handler.proceed(); // Ignore SSL certificate errors
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I figured it out or just figured out a way around it. All I did was create a WebViewClient object and am using its methods. Code now looks like:

```
public class WebAuth extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_auth);
        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        SSLTolerantWebViewClient n = new SSLTolerantWebViewClient(); 
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(n);
        myWebView.loadUrl("example.com");
        n.onPageFinished(myWebView, "example.com"); This method doesn't appear, nor do any other WebViewClient methods

// other basic activity methods
}
```